# hasItems Assertion error with iterable containing

Tags: java, assertion, hamcrest, serenity-bdd

I am trying to assert that a list return the value that I need, but the assertion is failing and I don't know why if the difference is equals

```
theActorInTheSpotlight().should(seeThat(Elmenu.menu(SegurosVolutariosUi.CAMPOS_FORMULARIO_SEGUROS_VOLUTARIOS), contains(etiquetasFormulario)))
```

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable containing [<[Aseguradora, Tipo de seguro, Tipo de venta, Fecha de venta, Estado, Vendedor, Fecha de renovación, Origen]>]
     but: item 0: was "Aseguradora"
```

Comment: etiquetasFormulario is a List<String> and the menu method returns a List<String>

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for failure is that your approach tries to compares the whole collections, which doesn't equal.
If you want to check presence of single/multiple items you can use hasItem(s) matchers.

```
// direct check for a single value
theActorInTheSpotlight().should(seeThat(Elmenu.menu(SegurosVolutariosUi.CAMPOS_FORMULARIO_SEGUROS_VOLUTARIOS), hasItem("Aseguradora")))
// or just make an array with items from the list
theActorInTheSpotlight().should(seeThat(Elmenu.menu(SegurosVolutariosUi.CAMPOS_FORMULARIO_SEGUROS_VOLUTARIOS), hasItems(etiquetasFormulario.toArray(new String[0]))))
```